# How do I stop Fields being rendered twice for a node with Paragraph Types using UI Patterns?

Tags: paragraphs, bootstrap-theme

I'm using UI Patterns within Paragraph Types which is resulting in the Fields being rendered twice in the theme. I'm using a sub theme of the bootsrap5 contrib theme. I have a custom layout twig:-

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a two-column layout.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - in_preview: Whether the plugin is being rendered in preview mode.
 * - content: The content for this layout.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the layout <div>.
 */
#}

{%
    set classes = [
        'col-12',
        'col-md-9',
        'col-md-3',
    ]
%}

{% if content %}
    <div{{attributes.addClass('container')}}>
        <div{{attributes.addClass('row')}}>

            {% if content.first %}
                <div {{ region_attributes.first.addClass(classes).removeClass('col-md-9') }}>
                    {{ content.first }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            {% if content.second %}
                <div {{ region_attributes.second.addClass(classes).removeClass('col-md-3') }}>
                    {{ content.second }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}

        </div>

    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Screenshot of the result:-

[image: screenshot of duplicate fields]

The resulting HTML is below:-

```
<div class="field field--name-field-components field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden field__items">
              <div class="field__item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'paragraph' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * paragraph--section--default.html.twig
   * paragraph--section.html.twig
   * paragraph--default.html.twig
   x paragraph.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/paragraphs/templates/paragraph.html.twig' -->
  <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--section paragraph--view-mode--default">
          

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'pa_third_2thirds' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x pa-third-2thirds.html.twig
   x pa-third-2thirds.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/layouts/pa-third-2thirds.html.twig' -->


    <div class="container">
        <div class="container row">

                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'ds_entity_view' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'pattern_alert' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--100056.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--100056.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning.html.twig
   x pattern-alert.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/alert/pattern-alert.html.twig' -->
  
  
<div class="alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show alert">
    <h4 class="alert-heading">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--default--paragraph--field-alert-heading--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--default--field-alert-heading--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--default.html.twig
   * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-alert-heading--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--string.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div class="field field--name-field-alert-heading field--type-string field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Heading</div>
              <div class="field__item">This is the heading!</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

</h4>
    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--default--paragraph--field-simple-text--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--default--field-simple-text--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--default.html.twig
   * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-simple-text--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--string-long.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div class="field field--name-field-simple-text field--type-string-long field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Message</div>
              <div class="field__item">Hello! I'm a message!</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->


      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/alert/pattern-alert.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->


                </div>
            
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'ds_entity_view' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'pattern_card' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--100057.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--100057.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default.html.twig
   x pattern-card.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/card/pattern-card.html.twig' -->
<div class="card">
      

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--default--paragraph--field-card-media--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--default--field-card-media--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--default.html.twig
   * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-card-media--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   x field--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--entity-reference.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/overrides/field/field--field-card-media.html.twig' -->

  <div class="field field--name-field-card-media field--type-entity-reference field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Card image</div>
              <div class="field__item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->
  

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->
<img src="/sites/default/files/2023-01/turkeys.png" width="400" height="400" alt="turkeys" loading="lazy" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-fluid">

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->

</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/overrides/field/field--field-card-media.html.twig' -->


      <div class="card-header">
    
  </div>
    
    <div class="card-footer">
    
  </div>
    </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/card/pattern-card.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->


                </div>
            
        </div>

    </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/layouts/pa-third-2thirds.html.twig' -->


      </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/paragraphs/templates/paragraph.html.twig' -->

</div>
              <div class="field__item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'ds_entity_view' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'pattern_alert' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--100056.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--100056.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-alert--variant-warning.html.twig
   x pattern-alert.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/alert/pattern-alert.html.twig' -->
  
  
<div class="alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show alert">
    <h4 class="alert-heading">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--default--paragraph--field-alert-heading--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--default--field-alert-heading--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--default.html.twig
   * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-alert-heading--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--field-alert-heading.html.twig
   * field--string.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div class="field field--name-field-alert-heading field--type-string field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Heading</div>
              <div class="field__item">This is the heading!</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

</h4>
    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--default--paragraph--field-simple-text--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--default--field-simple-text--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--default--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--default.html.twig
   * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-simple-text--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--ui-suite-test.html.twig
   * field--field-simple-text.html.twig
   * field--string-long.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div class="field field--name-field-simple-text field--type-string-long field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Message</div>
              <div class="field__item">Hello! I'm a message!</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->


      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/alert/pattern-alert.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->

</div>
              <div class="field__item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'ds_entity_view' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'pattern_card' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--100057.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--100057.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--default.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout--paragraph.html.twig
   * pattern-card--layout.html.twig
   * pattern-card--variant-default.html.twig
   x pattern-card.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/card/pattern-card.html.twig' -->
<div class="card">
      

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--default--paragraph--field-card-media--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--paragraph--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--default--field-card-media--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--default--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--default.html.twig
   * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-card-media--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--ui-suite-card.html.twig
   x field--field-card-media.html.twig
   * field--entity-reference.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/overrides/field/field--field-card-media.html.twig' -->

  <div class="field field--name-field-card-media field--type-entity-reference field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Card image</div>
              <div class="field__item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->
  

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->
<img src="/sites/default/files/2023-01/turkeys.png" width="400" height="400" alt="turkeys" loading="lazy" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-fluid">

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->

</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/overrides/field/field--field-card-media.html.twig' -->


      <div class="card-header">
    
  </div>
    
    <div class="card-footer">
    
  </div>
    </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/b5subtheme/templates/patterns/card/pattern-card.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig' -->

</div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So this turned out to be a face palm and a half!

The Field in question had the Display set to "Rendered Entity" with no "UI Limit".

Changing the "UI Limit" to 1 fixed it.

However, as this is a Paragraph Type the Display should really be "Paragraph Type".

Hope this helps anyone experiencing this problem!

Comment: I have this issue on Drupal 10, and there is no admin field to adjust this. :(